# Is it possible to calculate the distance between two points in space if time dilation difference is known?

Tags: time-dilation

If 19.4 minutes have passed on Earth and correspondingly 116.64 million years have passed on another place (Brahma loka), is it possible for me to find the distance between Earth and the other place from just this data? I do not have any foundation in Physics, so layman explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: No. You also need to know the details of the gravitational structure of the universe. But such a massive time difference would require a huge gravity source, like a black hole, or speed very close to lightspeed. BTW, questions related to Vedic cosmology are off-topic here.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's Brahma loka or not. Just presume it to be some random place. Also, i found this time dilation calculator online. http://www.emc2-explained.info/Dilation-Calc/#.XW_0Ne7hU_D This calculator shows me the time dilation if i put in the percent of light speed my speed was and the distance in light years. Can you figure out a way to find distance if other details are given and my speed is, say 99 percent of light speed?

Comment: As I said before, there *isn't* a way to find the distance, it could be anything. Also, you need to be *much* closer to the speed of light than 99% to get that huge amount of time dilation.